# How to make multiple update record for a field which can take atmost 3 values in sql

Tags: sql, sql-update

I have an employee table, and `gender` is one of the columns. How can I update the male gender to female and vice-verse?

Comment: Can you share your attempts so far?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how you store the `gender` column they may be a niftier trick available, but assuming it's a straight forward `varchar` column the has the values `M` and `F` (or `male` and `female` - same logic), you could use a `case` statement:

```
UPDATE employee
SET    gender = CASE gender WHEN 'M' THEN 'F' WHEN 'F' THEN 'M' ELSE NULL END;
```

**note:**
Based on the "at most three values" statement in the OP's title, I'm assuming that `null`s are allowed, and should remain unchanged. If this is not true, the `case` expression could be simplified.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name that was embarrassing :(. Did even notice I typed that (yes, **despite** the syntax highlighting).